# MySQL calcualge difference in select query

Tags: php, mysql, select, difference

I was wondering if it was possible to do basic math in a select query.  Say i have the following table

```
+----------+----------+
| name     |   score  |
+----------+----------+
| Person 1 |     5    |
+----------+----------+
| Person 1 |     8    |
+----------+----------+
| Person 1 |     3    |
+----------+----------+
| Person 2 |     7    |
+----------+----------+
| Person 1 |     9    |
+----------+----------+
```

Currently I am using the following to get data.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name='Person 1'
```

I want to select all data but also include a column for the score difference (taking the WHERE clause into consideration) so the result would be something like

```
+----------+----------+------------+
| name     |   score  | difference |
+----------+----------+------------+
| Person 1 |     5    |      0     |
+----------+----------+------------+
| Person 1 |     8    |      3     |
+----------+----------+------------+
| Person 1 |     3    |      -5    |
+----------+----------+------------+
| Person 1 |     9    |      6     |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

Is it possible to achieve this with just a single select query?

Thanks

Comment: you need to tell us how `difference` is being computed, ie `person 2 score - person 1 score = difference` ??

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear was it?  Difference would be the difference between the current score and the previous score for the same person.  i.e. in row 2, difference is 8 - 5. In row four it is 3 - 8 etc

Comment: then how do you get 2 for 9?

Comment: Easy. You copy and paste someone else's work without checking it. Sorry, it is late.  I have edited the question now

Comment: How do you know which score go before another ? Do you have a timestamp in `my_table` ?

Comment: I do have a timestamp, but was hoping to do it simply in the order they appear in the database.  If a timestamp is needed or just best practice, happy to use that.

Comment: @Typhoon101 Timestamp will allow you to add entries later for previous dates. ie: Server was having issues on Friday, and we had to wait until Monday to enter them. But another test had already happened. Also makes sorting the test consistent.

Comment: In real life, the data will be entered once a month and will never be late, but I see your point. I will be happy to include the timestamp field

Comment: Careful: There's no such thing as "the order [rows] appear in the database."  Result sets from SQL queries are, in the absence of `ORDER BY` clauses, presented by the server in formally unpredictable order.

Comment: A timestamp or an autoincrement ID field...something to sort on...

Comment: Okay, so I will settle with the timestamp.  How would the Select query go?  Can this even be done with a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   
  u.name, 
  u.score, 
  IFNULL((u.score - (SELECT score FROM users WHERE id = @previd)), 0) as difference,
  @prevId := u.id as id
FROM    users u, (SELECT @previd :=0) c
WHERE name = "Person 1"
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cd739/7)

With the above query you can `ORDER BY` any column.

Comment: Thanks. This is SOOO nearly it. I have just two questions. firstly, is the `@prevId := u.id as currentId` line necessary? It seems to just add a column for the ID, but I already have that elsewhere. Can I do without it? Secondly, the first row seems to be calculating the difference between the first score and the score in the last row. Can this be zero instead as the first row has no previous row? (hope that makes sense)

Comment: That line sets the @prevId variable which is used in the line above it. in order to properly set the variable you need to have that column in the select statement.

Comment: I am sorry, I appreciate your help, but this has stopped working for me.  Here is my actual setup. [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00af1/1). My table shows how much fruit a person has picked in a given week by weight (lbs). (it is part of an education game i am building for my daughter). The error I am seeing is `[2014-12-29 23:23:19] [22007][1292] Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '8kzMZfXFNv1dGEY'`

Comment: Okay, I have nearly got this working. If i remove the `(SELECT @prevId :=0) c` from the FROM line, everything works. I have no idea what that does, so is it necessary? [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5955e/1).  Also, in places you have @previd and in others you have @prevId. Is this case sensitive?

Comment: @Typhoon101 the `(SELECT @prevId :=0) c` resets the variable back to 0 when the query is finished since variables will persist and running a query multiple times can cause issues. the error you have is because the `(SELECT @prevId :=0) c` sets it to a integer value and you are using a varchar value, change `(SELECT @prevId :=0) c` to `(SELECT @prevId := NULL) c`. Yes MySQL is case insensitive, however not best practice to mix cases.

Answer (score 0):

first, you will need to add an increment column to your table. in my example it's called (no surprises) 'id'. it's an autoincrement. your current table doesn't look like it has a possible primary key, so an auto increment column is a good idea anyway.

this solution uses some simple subselects to get the largest id that is smaller than the id of the current row you are selecting, ie the 'previous' row. from there it's simple subtraction to get the score difference.

```
select a.id, 
       a.name, 
       a.score, 
       a.score-(select   score  
                from     my_table 
                where    id=(select   max(id) 
                             from     my_table 
                             where    id<a.id 
                             and      name="person 1")) as difference 
from   my_table a 
where  name="person 1";
```

hope this does the trick!